# Proguard problems

Tags: android, proguard

I have some issues with proguard. Tried tons of adding to rules. But nothing seems to work. What i did find out is that the problem occured when we upgraded the Moshi vesion. But we cant downgrade it since we do need it.

We also have followed what kind of proguard rules the moshi library needs. Added them all but still it crashes when we try to do a network call.

Let me know if you want to see anything else to be able to accurately help.

Right now any nudge in the right direction is appreciated. Trying to solve this mess

```
W/System.err: io.reactivex.exceptions.UndeliverableException: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KotlinReflectionInternalError: Call is not yet supported for this function: public constructor AccountHolder(accountHolderId: kotlin.String, accountHolderName: kotlin.String) defined in com.core.network.model.response.AccountHolder[DeserializedClassConstructorDescriptor@c71e978] (member = null)
W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.plugins.RxJavaPlugins.onError(RxJavaPlugins.java:367)
W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.internal.observers.ConsumerSingleObserver.onSuccess(ConsumerSingleObserver.java:66)
W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleDoOnSuccess$DoOnSuccess.onSuccess(SingleDoOnSuccess.java:59)
W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleDoOnError$DoOnError.onSuccess(SingleDoOnError.java:52)
W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleDoOnSubscribe$DoOnSubscribeSingleObserver.onSuccess(SingleDoOnSubscribe.java:77)
W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleObserveOn$ObserveOnSingleObserver.run(SingleObserveOn.java:81)
W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.android.schedulers.HandlerScheduler$ScheduledRunnable.run(HandlerScheduler.java:109)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6940)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
W/System.err: Caused by: kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KotlinReflectionInternalError: Call is not yet supported for this function: public constructor AccountHolder(accountHolderId: kotlin.String, accountHolderName: kotlin.String) defined in com.core.network.model.response.AccountHolder[DeserializedClassConstructorDescriptor@c71e978] (member = null)
W/System.err:     at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KFunctionImpl$caller$2.invoke(KFunctionImpl.kt:89)
W/System.err:     at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KFunctionImpl$caller$2.invoke(KFunctionImpl.kt:34)
W/System.err:     at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.ReflectProperties$LazySoftVal.invoke(ReflectProperties.java:93)
W/System.err:     at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.ReflectProperties$Val.getValue(ReflectProperties.java:32)
W/System.err:     at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KFunctionImpl.getCaller(Unknown Source:7)
W/System.err:     at kotlin.reflect.jvm.ReflectJvmMapping.getJavaMethod(ReflectJvmMapping.kt:62)
W/System.err:     at kotlin.reflect.jvm.KCallablesJvm.setAccessible(KCallablesJvm.kt:81)
W/System.err:     at com.squareup.moshi.kotlin.reflect.KotlinJsonAdapterFactory.create(KotlinJsonAdapter.kt:196)
W/System.err:     at com.squareup.moshi.Moshi.adapter(Moshi.java:130)
W/System.err:     at com.squareup.moshi.Moshi.adapter(Moshi.java:64)
W/System.err:     at com.squareup.moshi.CollectionJsonAdapter.newArrayListAdapter(CollectionJsonAdapter.java:52)
W/System.err:     at com.squareup.moshi.CollectionJsonAdapter$1.create(CollectionJsonAdapter.java:36)
W/System.err:     at com.squareup.moshi.Moshi.adapter(Moshi.java:130)
W/System.err:     at com.squareup.moshi.kotlin.reflect.KotlinJsonAdapterFactory.create(KotlinJsonAdapter.kt:231)
W/System.err:     at com.squareup.moshi.Moshi.adapter(Moshi.java:130)
W/System.err:     at retrofit2.converter.moshi.MoshiConverterFactory.responseBodyConverter(MoshiConverterFactory.java:91)
W/System.err:     at retrofit2.Retrofit.nextResponseBodyConverter(Retrofit.java:330)
W/System.err:     at retrofit2.Retrofit.responseBodyConverter(Retrofit.java:313)
W/System.err:     at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.createResponseConverter(ServiceMethod.java:739)
W/System.err:     at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.build(ServiceMethod.java:172)
W/System.err:     at retrofit2.Retrofit.loadServiceMethod(Retrofit.java:170)
W/System.err:     at retrofit2.Retrofit$1.invoke(Retrofit.java:147)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:913)
W/System.err:     at $Proxy1.getAuthenticationVerify(Unknown Source)
W/System.err:     at com.component.main.intro.impl.IntroFragmentInteractor.verifyAuthentication(IntroFragmentInteractor.kt:19)
W/System.err:     at com.component.main.intro.impl.IntroFragmentPresenter.verifyAuthentication(IntroFragmentPresenter.kt:95)
W/System.err:     at com.component.main.intro.impl.IntroFragmentPresenter.handleIdFinished(IntroFragmentPresenter.kt:90)
W/System.err:     at com.component.main.intro.impl.IntroFragmentPresenter$startAuthentication$1.accept(IntroFragmentPresenter.kt:74)
W/System.err:     at com.component.main.intro.impl.IntroFragmentPresenter$startAuthentication$1.accept(IntroFragmentPresenter.kt:26)
W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.internal.observers.ConsumerSingleObserver.onSuccess(ConsumerSingleObserver.java:63)
W/System.err:   ... 12 more
```

**Proguard module 1**

```
    -keep class com.shared.** { *;}
-dontwarn com.shared.**
#

-keep public class * implements com.bumptech.glide.module.GlideModule
-keep public class * extends com.bumptech.glide.module.AppGlideModule
-keep public enum com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.ImageHeaderParser$** {
  **[] $VALUES;
  public *;
}



-dontwarn com.google.common.**
-dontwarn ch.qos.logback.**
-dontwarn dagger.android.**
-dontwarn io.reactivex.**
-dontwarn com.crashlytics.**
-dontwarn okhttp3.**
-dontwarn okio.**
-dontwarn javax.annotation.**
-dontwarn org.conscrypt.**
-dontwarn retrofit2.Platform$Java8

-keep class io.reactivex.** { *; }
-keep class ch.qos.** { *; }
-keep class org.slf4j.** { *; }

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-dontwarn org.jetbrains.annotations.**
-keep class kotlin.Metadata { *; }

-keepclassmembers enum * { *; }

-keep public class * extends java.lang.Exception
-keep @com.squareup.moshi.JsonQualifier interface *
-keep class com.crashlytics.** { *; }

-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @com.squareup.moshi.* <methods>;
}
-keepnames class okhttp3.internal.publicsuffix.PublicSuffixDatabase

#//Moshi
-keep class kotlin.** { *; }
-keep class org.jetbrains.** { *; }
-dontwarn okio.**
-dontwarn javax.annotation.**
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @com.squareup.moshi.* <methods>;
}
-keep @com.squareup.moshi.JsonQualifier interface *

-keepclassmembers class kotlin.Metadata {
    public <methods>;
}

-keep class **JsonAdapter {
    <init>(...);
    <fields>;
}
-keepclassmembers class my.models.package.** {
  <init>(...);
  <fields>;
}
-keepnames @com.squareup.moshi.JsonClass class *
-keepclassmembers class ** {
  @org.jetbrains.annotations.ReadOnly public *;
}

-dontwarn kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.descriptors.CallableDescriptor
-dontwarn kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.descriptors.ClassDescriptor
-dontwarn kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.descriptors.ClassifierDescriptorWithTypeParameters
-dontwarn kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.descriptors.annotations.AnnotationDescriptor
-dontwarn kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.descriptors.impl.PropertyDescriptorImpl
-dontwarn kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.load.java.JavaClassFinder
-dontwarn kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.resolve.OverridingUtil
-dontwarn kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.types.DescriptorSubstitutor
-dontwarn kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.types.DescriptorSubstitutor
-dontwarn kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.types.TypeConstructor

# Retrofit
# Platform calls Class.forName on types which do not exist on Android to determine platform.
-dontnote retrofit2.Platform
# Platform used when running on Java 8 VMs. Will not be used at runtime.
-dontwarn retrofit2.Platform$Java8
# Retain generic type information for use by reflection by converters and adapters.
-keepattributes Signature
# Retain declared checked exceptions for use by a Proxy instance.
-keepattributes Exceptions

-keep public class kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.builtins.* { public *; }
-keep class com.squareup.moshi.** { *; }
-keep interface com.squareup.moshi.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.squareup.moshi.**
-keepclassmembers class ** {
    @com.squareup.moshi.FromJson *;
    @com.squareup.moshi.ToJson *;
}
#Rx
-dontwarn sun.misc.**

-keepclassmembers class rx.internal.util.unsafe.*ArrayQueue*Field* {
   long producerIndex;
   long consumerIndex;
}
-keep class kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.** { *; }

-keepclassmembers class rx.internal.util.unsafe.BaseLinkedQueueProducerNodeRef {
    rx.internal.util.atomic.LinkedQueueNode producerNode;
}

-keepclassmembers class rx.internal.util.unsafe.BaseLinkedQueueConsumerNodeRef {
    rx.internal.util.atomic.LinkedQueueNode consumerNode;
}

-dontnote rx.internal.util.PlatformDependent

-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keep class com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }
-keep interface com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**

-keepclasseswithmembers class com.squareup.moshi.kotlin.reflect.KotlinJsonAdapterFactory * {
    *;
}
-keep class kotlin.reflect.**
-keep class com.squareup.moshi.**
-keep class retrofit2.converter.moshi.**
-keep class retrofit2.**
```

**Proguard module 2**

```
-dontobfuscate

-dontwarn com.google.common.**
-dontwarn ch.qos.logback.**
-dontwarn dagger.android.**
-dontwarn io.reactivex.**
-dontwarn com.crashlytics.**
-dontwarn okhttp3.**
-dontwarn okio.**
-dontwarn javax.annotation.**
-dontwarn org.conscrypt.**
-dontwarn retrofit2.Platform$Java8

-keep class io.reactivex.** { *; }
-keep class ch.qos.** { *; }
-keep class org.slf4j.** { *; }

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keepclassmembers enum * { *; }

-keep public class * extends java.lang.Exception
-keep @com.squareup.moshi.JsonQualifier interface *
-keep class com.crashlytics.** { *; }

-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable

-keepclassmembers class kotlin.Metadata {
    public <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @com.squareup.moshi.* <methods>;
}
-keepnames class okhttp3.internal.publicsuffix.PublicSuffixDatabase

#//Moshi

-keep class com.squareup.moshi.** { *; }
-keep interface com.squareup.moshi.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.squareup.moshi.**

-keepclassmembers class ** {
    @com.squareup.moshi.FromJson *;
    @com.squareup.moshi.ToJson *;
}

-keep class kotlin.** { *; }
-keep class org.jetbrains.** { *; }
-dontwarn okio.**
-dontwarn javax.annotation.**
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @com.squareup.moshi.* <methods>;
}
-keep @com.squareup.moshi.JsonQualifier interface *

-keep class **JsonAdapter {
    <init>(...);
    <fields>;
}
-keepclassmembers class my.models.package.** {
  <init>(...);
  <fields>;
}
-keepnames @com.squareup.moshi.JsonClass class *
-keepclassmembers class ** {
  @org.jetbrains.annotations.ReadOnly public *;
}
-keep class kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.** { *; }


-dontwarn kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.descriptors.CallableDescriptor
-dontwarn kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.descriptors.ClassDescriptor
-dontwarn kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.descriptors.ClassifierDescriptorWithTypeParameters
-dontwarn kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.descriptors.annotations.AnnotationDescriptor
-dontwarn kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.descriptors.impl.PropertyDescriptorImpl
-dontwarn kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.load.java.JavaClassFinder
-dontwarn kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.resolve.OverridingUtil
-dontwarn kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.types.DescriptorSubstitutor
-dontwarn kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.types.DescriptorSubstitutor
-dontwarn kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.types.TypeConstructor

# Retrofit
# Platform calls Class.forName on types which do not exist on Android to determine platform.
-dontnote retrofit2.Platform
# Platform used when running on Java 8 VMs. Will not be used at runtime.
-dontwarn retrofit2.Platform$Java8
# Retain generic type information for use by reflection by converters and adapters.
-keepattributes Signature
# Retain declared checked exceptions for use by a Proxy instance.
-keepattributes Exceptions

-keep public class kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.builtins.* { public *; }

#Rx
-dontwarn sun.misc.**

-keepclassmembers class rx.internal.util.unsafe.*ArrayQueue*Field* {
   long producerIndex;
   long consumerIndex;
}

-keepclassmembers class rx.internal.util.unsafe.BaseLinkedQueueProducerNodeRef {
    rx.internal.util.atomic.LinkedQueueNode producerNode;
}

-keepclassmembers class rx.internal.util.unsafe.BaseLinkedQueueConsumerNodeRef {
    rx.internal.util.atomic.LinkedQueueNode consumerNode;
}

-dontnote rx.internal.util.PlatformDependent
```

Comment: do share your proguard file

Comment: I have added both of them. The project is sepparated into multiple modules. The rules are pretty big. Because i have added tons of thing when i tried to solve it

Comment: sure not an issue

Comment: Which version of Moshi are you using ? I assume you were using latest, still to clarify

Comment: yes we are using the latest one